# Library property, org.zkoss.zul.chart.engine.class, required

Tags: zk

I am trying to use the charts in a Maven project for `zk` but get this error

```
Library property, org.zkoss.zul.chart.engine.class, required
```

On the outline the chart icon is there.

any ideas what maven dependency I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mentioned which ZK version you are talking about here or its a `CE` or `EE` or any other product of ZK.

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zkforge</groupId>
            <artifactId>flashchart</artifactId>
            <version>${version.zk}</version>
        </dependency>
```

For your reference you can check [ZK Chart Exception](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/54590/problem-with-zk-charts/)

**EDIT**

For further details about feature in differnt version of ZK you can check [Features Comparison between CE,EE,PE version](http://www.zkoss.org/whyzk/Features)

Comment: thanks, I just downloaded zk studio plugin, the charts were working in non maven projects though so not sure why I need the EE version..

Comment: I'm a bit confused I just downloaded 5.6.1 CE.  I a don't see a way to attach this to my project, am I supposed to use maven deps, or just drag those jars from my download into my project?

Comment: See the link added by me